# How can I get download location browser in spring mvc controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, printing

The problem is next necessary to make file on server and after sending to client and print.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFileForPrint(HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long id,
        @RequestParam(value = "print", defaultValue = "false") Boolean print) throws Exception {

    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + fname);

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    somefile.write(out);
    Desktop.getDesktop.print(new File("download location browser"));}
}
```

Comment: Pavel Please describe your problem better. I'm unable to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Describe what goes wrong, e.g file is not created or you see errors, update your post with this information please.

Comment: I have task send  excel file from java server to client printer, when client  (in my case is jquery)  click button. How can I do it ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by when you are hitting an end point you want to download a file immediately then the following code should help you.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/somePath", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getFileForPrint(HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long id,
        @RequestParam(value = "print", defaultValue = "false") Boolean print) throws Exception {
        String filename="nameOfFileWhenDownloaded.txt";
        try {
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
            osw.write(contentsOfTheFile);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Error is sending file");
        }
}
```

Comment: I am so sorry. It was bad explanation. More correctly. 
I have a task to send Excel file from java server to the client printer, when client  (in my case is jquery)  click button.